# If CSV file not exsist then function keep adding empty rows in to database

Tags: php, cakephp, csv

I need a little help. I have a Model file, this imports a CSV file in to the database. But my model file takes this CSV from the `C:\wamp\www\cakephp-2.5.6\app\tmp\uploads\Kontaktid` and if CSV file named `export.csv` not exsist in this folder, then my function keep adding empty rows in to database.

Can I do something like this (I tried to add this in to Controller, but this is not working) ?

```
If empty(Kontaktid) {

   echo ("CSV file is not found");exit;
}
```

This is my Controller file:

```
function import() {
            $this->Kontaktid->import('export.csv');
        }
```

And this is my Model file:

```
<?php  

class Kontaktid extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(
        'title' => array('rule' => 'notEmpty'),
        'body' => array('rule' => 'notEmpty')
    );
    var $name = 'Kontaktid';
    function import($filename) {
        // set the filename to read CSV from
        $filename = TMP . 'uploads' . DS . 'Kontaktid' . DS . $filename;
        // open the file
        $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
        // read the 1st row as headings
        $header = fgetcsv($handle);
        // read each data row in the file
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $this->query ("INSERT into kontaktids(id,Eesnimi,Perenimi,Maakond,Linn,Tanav,Maja,Telefon,lisanumbrid) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]','$data[8]')");
            $this->query;
        }
         print "Import done";
        // close the file
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping !

Comment: There are a lot of ways to check if a file does exists :)

Comment: I belive, but I didnt found a solution . :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using :

```
<?php
$filename = '/path/to/export.csv';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    // do your import stuff.
} else {
    // File is not exist.
}
?>
```

Check this link for more info : http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: I already used this, but anyway its inserting empty rows in to database

Comment: its outbuts this "File not exist", and then its keep adding empty rows in to database

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest don't code it by yourself, here is awesome library which can parse the `csv` for you https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php

```
function import($filename) {
            // set the filename to read CSV from
            $filename = TMP . 'uploads' . DS . 'Kontaktid' . DS . $filename;
            if (file_exists($filename)) {
                // do your import stuff.
                // open the file
            $csv = new parseCSV($filename);
            //print_r($csv->data);
            //count the rows
                if( count($csv->data) > 0) {
                    foreach($csv->data as $data) {
                       $this->query ("INSERT into kontaktids(id,Eesnimi,Perenimi,Maakond,Linn,Tanav,Maja,Telefon,lisanumbrid) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]','$data[8]')");
                       $this->query;
                    }
                }
                print "Import done";
            } else {
               print "File is not exist";.
         }  
}
```

Comment: Ye, this working too . But hardik answer was what I was looking for. Thanks !

Comment: and this is going to view file ?

Comment: I added `function import {` and its says `unexpected '{', expecting '('` why ?

Comment: and if I replace `{` with `(` , then it says  `unexpected 'new' (T_NEW)`

Comment: updated the answer, it should work, don't forget to include `parseCSV` library using composer

Comment: okay, I did it, but he still says that Class 'parseCSV' not found

Comment: you need to include this class https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php/blob/master/parsecsv.lib.php first before calling `parseCSV` function

Comment: Yea I know , I tried this, and parseCSV works, but this all thing was not working right. I use better my code ;) But thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The `while`condition should check if the return value is `NULL` too. Which is the case if the file is invalid. 
source:http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php